# Can we define 'Norm' over an arbitrary vector space which may not be real or complex vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis

While we define norm on a vector space, we consider only real or complex vector field. But can we generalize this norm on a vector space over an arbitrary field ? I think this can be done, but we have to define a suitable modulus function on the ground field to be meaningful in the property ||cx||=|c|||x||, what |c| means. Is this possible to define norm in this general situation? And why we only bother about real or complex vector space?

Comment: For sure! In number theory, we often consider vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$, and we can define $|c|$ as the absolute value for all scalars $c \in \mathbb{Q}$. I'm not sure whether this can be extended to finite fields though ... I'll leave that for others to answer.

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space): "Other choices are possible. For example, for a vector space over 
$\mathbb {Q}$  one could take 
$|\alpha |$ to be the $p$-adic norm, which gives rise to a different class of normed vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be a field and $V$ a vector space over $F$. Define $|\cdot |: F \to \mathbb{R}$ by $|f| = 1$ for $f \ne 0 $ and $|0| = 0$. Define $\| \cdot \| : V \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\|v \| = 1$ for $v \ne 0$ and $\| 0\| = 0$.

Then $\|v\| \geq 0$, $\|v\| = 0\iff v =0 $, if $\lambda \ne 0$ and $v \ne 0$, then $\lambda v \ne 0 $ and $\|\lambda v \| = 1 = |\lambda| \|v\|$, otherwise $\lambda v = 0$ and $|\lambda| \|v\| = 0$, so $\|\lambda v\| = |\lambda |\|v\|$ either way.

Finally as long at least one of $v$ or $w$ is nonzero, then $\|v + w\| \leq 1 \leq \|v\| + \|w\|$, else $v = w = 0$, so $\|v+w\| = \|0\| =0 \leq 0 + 0 = \|v\| + \|w\|$.

So we have define a not very interesting norm on an arbitrary vector space over an arbitrary field. Note we need to define a norm on the field, which should follow the positive definiteness requirement as well as triangle inequality (which ours does) and maybe also a multiplicativity requirement: $|ab| = |a||b|$ (which ours does also).

Finally, as was commented, there are more interesting norm on number fields in number theory. But this shows it always possible in some sense.

Answer (score 0):

We can (at least sometimes) even define a norm on a module over a ring, a notion which generalizes that of a vector space.

One interesting example is the Gaußian integers, $\Bbb Z[i]$.  An arbitrary element looks like $a+bi, a,b\in\Bbb Z$.

If you define the "norm" by $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$, it has the nice property of being multiplicative.